# How to mount an LVM from Read-only to Read and Write

Tags: linux, lvm, readonly

I have a VM with an LVM. Occasionally when updates are performed, and the system has restarted it will go into a read-only state. This is an issue because I perform daily backups.
Unfortunately, for me, I have been assigned to fix this issue since our sysadmin is on leave.
I have a snapshot folder that backs up every day that is now read-only.
I run the following command:

```
[root@aetest /]# mount -o remount /snapshots
```

After doing this nothing happens. no error, loading, or any indication it worked.
I then move over to the snapshot folder and type the following:

```
[root@aetest /]# touch mytest.dat
```

and I get this:

```
touch: cannot touch "mytest.dat": Read-only file system
```

Any ideas of what I can try? Lost here. thanks!

```
dmesg | tail 
[    7.148297] virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered listening state
[    7.148369] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): virbr0: link is not ready
[    7.228501] virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered disabled state
[50301439.170135] hrtimer: interrupt took 10774359 ns
[74288100.971099] fuse init (API version 7.22)
[74288166.623204] TCP: lp registered
[83201640.576424] CIFS VFS: Server SNAP2 has not responded in 120 seconds. Reconnecting...
[83201641.343342] CIFS VFS: Server SNAP2 has not responded in 120 seconds. Reconnecting...
[110561538.237685] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[110561538.261675] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
```

What was located in the /etc/fstab is pasted below. I am not seeing anything wrong here..

```
/dev/mapper/rhel-root   /  xfs     defaults        1 1
UUID=b45d9891-8384-4f1b-9deb-ee885707fc24 /boot   xfs     defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/rhel-swap   swap     swap    defaults        0 0
10.3.193.14:/prod_backups/q_uc4test_snapshots    /snapshots    nfs    ro,defaults    0 0
//SNAP2/UC4BDM  /opt/agent_library/finaid/snap2_uc4bdm  cifs    defaults,credentials=/etc/cifs.d/uc4finaid      0 0
//SNAP2/AdmAcct  /opt/agent_library/finaid/snap2_admacct  cifs    defaults,credentials=/etc/cifs.d/uc4finaid      0 0

[50301439.170135] hrtimer: interrupt took 10774359 ns
[74288100.971099] fuse init (API version 7.22)
[74288166.623204] TCP: lp registered
[83201640.576424] CIFS VFS: Server SNAP2 has not responded in 120 seconds. Reconnecting...
[83201641.343342] CIFS VFS: Server SNAP2 has not responded in 120 seconds. Reconnecting...
[110561538.237685] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[110561538.261675] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
```

Comment: What is the output of `mount`? What are the contents of `/etc/fstab`? What if you change the command ro `mount -o remount,rw /snapshots`?

Comment: If /etc/fstab contains the `ro` flag, it is normal that the filesystem is mounted read-only. If not, it might be mounted read-only because of inconsistencies, to prevent further damage to the data. I would check for relevant kernel messages, for example `dmesg | tail` right after mounting, or `journalctl -k -e` if systemd is used. I would also run the filesystem checker that is appropriate for the filesystem type, for example `xfs_repair` or `fsck`. You should find the filesystem type in /etc/fstab, or run `blkid` as superuser.

Comment: I've looked through both of your suggestions but I am not seeing anything other than an `I/0 error` on `snap2`. Which I don't use a floppy. I've added the code from `fstab` and `dmesg` if you people want to have a look.

Comment: There is no content that appears when I run mount. Just proceeds to accept another command.

Comment: looks like C.M. Was correct. mount -o remount, rw /snapshots resolved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For anybody else reading this and wanting a clearer answer:

- Is it the *filesystem* vs the *device* that is readonly.

If it's the filesystem, then per the comments:

```
mount -o remount,rw ${MOUNTPOINT_OR_DEVICE}
```

If it's the device, then you need:

```
lvchange --permission rw $VG/$LV
```

Comment: ....and if its a NFS/CIFS/other network filesystem then you also need write permission at the server.